# FastAPI: Cannot get error handling to work as expected

Tags: python, vue.js, fastapi

I am just learning FastAPI (and loving it), so it is quite likely I am doing something wrong.  But here is my problem:

In the code snippet below, I am creating a new user, *if* there is no user already.

The code works fine, but it is the error handling that I am having trouble with. The errors are properly being pushed forward to FastAPI's internal docs or to an API client like Postman, but not back to the actual client that I am using or the command line.

```py
@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_username(db, username=user.username)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail=f"Username '{user.username}' already registered"
        )
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)
```

---

If I use the auto-generated FastAPI docs (or Postman) and monitor the response in that way, I get the error I am expecting:

[image: Proper error response in API docs]

But when I look at what I am receiving **at the client end (Vue)** or what the **`uvicorn` server is logging**, it does not contain that information:

[image: Incorrect error response being logged]

As you can see, it just says `Bad Request` instead of responding with the JSON dict of `{"detail": "Username 'miketest' already registered"}`

---

What am I doing wrong?  What can I do to make sure that the full `HTTPException` information is being returned? I am pretty sure the problem is on the FastAPI end, because the client is receiving exactly what the server is outputting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and it was not a FastAPI issue, per se, but it was on how it passes information back to the front end.

I thought I should keep this question in case someone has the same issue.

---

Solution:

```
    try {
      await api().post('register',JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch (err) {
      error = err.response.data.detail;
    }
```

---

That is to say, the **error sent from FastAPI is an object that has a `response`, and in it a `data`, and in that a `detail`**.

The response from Postman or anything similar just gives an object with `detail`.  I did not see that there was a middle `data` layer, and I was having trouble seeing the entire object from within Vue.

Answer (score 2):

[This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW4Ol.png) belongs to console log and it will not contain the API response, the JSON response.

You can see the actual response if you send the request the API using some client, like [POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/).

Comment: Yes, @Arakkal.  I guess I did not make my point clear enough:  Yes, whether I use FastAPI docs or Postman, the API is returning the information of interest.  But when I use an *actual client*, or the command line, as I showed in my image, the information is being lost.  I updated the question to clarify this.

But, how do I get the resonse to the actual client (Vue) properly?  Do you know?

Comment: I am not familiar with *vue.js", but, interestingly, you said the response is being lost when you try with the command line. How did you try? Can you add the same in OP?

Comment: Sorry, when I said "command line", I meant the output that I get from the server when I launch it from the command line.  That is what I put in the question above; that's the screenshot with the blue background.

Comment: Are you expecting the json response [here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW4Ol.png)

Comment: Yes.  I guess I do not know now it works.  I have used Flask (Python) and Express (JS) as backends before, but I will admit I am not an expert.  I do not understand why FastAPI is providing complete output to Postman and to its internal API, but not to the server log nor back to Vue.

Comment: Usualy, none of the frameworks will not emit logs to **stdout**. If your vue does not received any JSON response but the POSTMAN does, it means the problem likely in your vue code base.